# How should a series of articles be represented on my CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I authored a series of three articles that were published in the same source over the course of a month or so. Each article has the same title with a different subtitle. Due to the identical titles, I find that the publications look somewhat awkward when listed separately on my CV:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: Quot tota id pri. Research Institute Magazine, Nov. 30, 2017.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: Ne vim delenit laoreet dissentias. Research Institute Magazine, Nov. 16, 2017.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: Id cum fugit voluptua voluptatum. Research Institute Magazine, Nov. 1, 2017.

Is there an elegant way to group them? To my surprise, I have not found this issue addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it is just fine. It allows the interested reader of your CV to find the articles in question and peruse them, which is exactly what you want to achieve.

(As a side note, it is not uncommon for people to publish sequences of articles that start out the same, then have a roman numeral, and then some further text. For example numbers 34 and 47 on my list of publications are of this form: http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications.html#x-reviewed . Here is a much longer sequence by one of my teachers: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C6&q=heywood+rannacher&btnG= .)